# Terminal command that gives the type of computer you're on

Tags: terminal, command-line

I am running MATLAB code on two different computers, both with the same username.

I would like to **distinguish between the two Macs** by having the code identify that one system is a desktop, and the other a laptop.

Is there a Terminal command that will print the type of computer I am using (so I can implement the relevant function?)

Answer (score 5):

This command should work for you:

```
sysctl hw.model
```

This will return the Model Identifier for your machine. The below is an example for a mid-2012 Retina MacBook Pro:

```
Machine123:~ username$ sysctl hw.model
hw.model: MacBookPro10,1
```

Below are some references on Apple's site that describe Model Identifiers - there doesn't seem to be a single reference:

[MacBook Pro Model Identifiers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201300)

[MacBook Model Identifiers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201608)

[MacBook Air Model Identifiers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201862)

[iMac Model Identifers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201634)

[Mac Pro Model Identifiers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202888)

[Mac Mini Model Identifiers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201894)

Comment: This'll give you one of Apple's machine-readable strings, same as in _System Information -> Hardware -> Overview -> Model Identifier_. If you want to _reliably_ distinguish between desktops and laptops, you'll need to maintain a current and exhaustive list of Apple's model-ID prefixes (`PowerBook`, `MacBook`, `MacBookAir`, `MacBookPro` vs. `PowerMac`, `iMac`, `Macmini`, `MacPro`).

Comment: @BlacklightShining You should edit that information into the answer

Comment: @Mark No, _Scot_ should edit that information into the answer. The edit would add meaning, rather than just clarifying.

Comment: @BlacklightShining If you can improve the answer by editing an answer, please do so. This is how the site works.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: @BlacklightShining Thank you for the comment - I've edited my answer a bit to provide more information about what this command is returning...

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if your Mac contains a battery, a smart battery manager or a clamshell mode to distinguish between laptop and desktop.

Check the output of `ioreg -l > ~/Desktop/ioreg.txt` for proper strings.

E.g. on Lion (10.7.5) and probably newer operating systems you can use:

```
ioreg -l | grep SMB0
```

(SMB0 probably means **SM**art**B**attery)

or

```
ioreg -l | grep AppleClamshellCausesSleep
```

On a desktop you get **no** output and on a laptop you get an output similar to this:

```
    | +-o SMB0  <class IOACPIPlatformDevice, id 0x100000166, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (35 ms), retain 9>
```

or

```
    | | |   "AppleClamshellCausesSleep" = Yes
```